# Extract array values into a CSV file

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

Hi I have the following code from the site: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/23947/world-elevation-data-as-csv

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Path, PathPatch

csv_data = np.loadtxt('csv_data(lat/long/value).csv',skiprows=1,delimiter=',')
num_el = csv_data[:,0]
lat = csv_data[:,1]
lon = csv_data[:,2]
value = csv_data[:,3]

data = Dataset("elevation_data.grd",'r')
lon_range = data.variables['x_range'][:]
lat_range = data.variables['y_range'][:]
topo_range = data.variables['z_range'][:]
spacing = data.variables['spacing'][:]
dimension = data.variables['dimension'][:]
z = data.variables['z'][:]
lon_num =  dimension[0]
lat_num =  dimension[1]

etopo_lon = np.linspace(lon_range[0],lon_range[1],dimension[0])
etopo_lat = np.linspace(lat_range[0],lat_range[1],dimension[1])
topo = np.reshape(z, (lat_num, lon_num))

height = np.empty_like(num_el)
for i in range(len(num_el)): 
    desired_lat_idx = np.abs(etopo_lat - lat[i]).argmin()
    desired_lon_idx = np.abs(etopo_lon - lon[i]).argmin()
    height[i] = topo[desired_lat_idx,desired_lon_idx]
height[height<0]=0 

dfl= pd.DataFrame({
    'Latitude' : desired_lat_idx.reshape(-1),
    'Longitude': desired_lon_idx.reshape(-1),
    'Altitude': height.reshape(-1)
});
dfl.to_csv(path)
```

With this I can extract the elevation data that are in a file (are attached to the lat/long data from another CSV file. Now I want to write a new CSV file which is structured as follows Long/lat/Value/Altitude. I have tried it with the snipped

```
dfl= pd.DataFrame({
    'Latitude' : desired_lat_idx.reshape(-1),
    'Longitude': desired_lon_idx.reshape(-1),
    'Altitude': height.reshape(-1)
});
dfl.to_csv(path)
```

But I get the error

```
>>> dfl= pd.DataFrame({
...     'Latitude' : desired_lat_idx.reshape(-1),
...     'Longitude': desired_lon_idx.reshape(-1),
...     'Altitude': height.reshape(-1)
... });
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\UsersName\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 637, in __init__
    mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
  File "C:\UsersName\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 502, in dict_to_mgr
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)
  File "C:\UsersNameAppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 120, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = _extract_index(arrays)
  File "C:\UsersName\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 674, in _extract_index
    raise ValueError("All arrays must be of the same length")
ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length
>>>
```

how can I get around this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`desired_lat_idx` and `desired_lon_idx` will be overwritten each loop, so you'll have one value for each of them two (value from the last loop of `len(num_el)` while your height will have the same length as `num_el` since you change the value at index `i` in every loop.
Try to print `len` of `desired_lat_idx`, `desired_lon_idx` and `height` to check if I'm right.

Try:

```
height = np.empty_like(num_el)
for i in range(len(num_el)): 
    lat_idx = np.abs(etopo_lat - lat[i]).argmin()
    lon_idx = np.abs(etopo_lon - lon[i]).argmin()
    height[i] = topo[lat_idx,lon_idx]
height[height<0]=0 

dfl= pd.DataFrame({
    'Latitude' : lat.reshape(-1),
    'Longitude': lon.reshape(-1),
    'Altitude': height.reshape(-1)
})
```

Comment: Do you mean that:

Comment: >>> print(len(desired_lat_idx))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()
>>> print(len(desired_lon_idx))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()
>>> print(len(height))
360000

Comment: oops, it proves my point but I didn't think of that. Yes, `desired_lat_idx` is one integer which obviously has no `len`. As you can see you want to create a `df` which has two columns of length 1 and one column of length 360000

Comment: did your code snipded solve my problem? Yes I can see your point however I#m new at coding and dont know how to extract the values right!

Comment: I tryed youre snipped but without sucsess

Comment: I can't tell you if that makes sense what you are calculating, but I know if you have a loop and calculate stuff in it and save it to a variable, this variable will be overwritten in each loop. But if you store the new value in each iteration at index `i`, nothing gets overwritten

Comment: what do you mean by "no success". what failed? did you get an error message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245850/discussion-between-weiss-and-rabinzel).

Comment: Hi @Rabinzel I hat a smale problem (see in my question)

Comment: how can I change the oriantation of the elevation data

Comment: come to the chat again